# IOS-9 - Wifi - radio enabled/disable through Application

Tags: ios, ios9, wifi

I have apple device with IOS - 9, device has wi-fi radio.

I am making application for IOS-9 device.

once I install application on IOS-9 device, is it possible to turn on wifi radio of that device through application ?

is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no API for doing that.